# Proof of Hilbert's nullstellensatz,

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $$K=\frac{k[x_1,\dots,x_n]}{m}$$
be a finitely generated $k$-algebra, where $m$ is a maximal ideal.
$K$ is algebraic over $k$. Then why is $k$ isomorphic to $K$? Sorry if this is obvious.

Comment: It's very hard to tell from your question where your confusion lies. Are you asking why, if $K$ is algebraic over $k$, then $K$ is isomorphic to $k$? That is by definition of $k$ being algebraically closed. This is definitely the most basic fact of the ones you've stated in your question, so please let us know if that is not your question

Answer (score 5):

Hint: (Zariski) If a field $L$ is ring-finite over a subfield $K$, then $L$ is module-finite (and hence algebraic) over $K$.

So if $I$ is a maximal ideal of $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$, then $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/I$ is a field, and so an algebraic extension
of $k$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, we get $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]/I$=k.

Comment: But I am trying to prove that all maximal ideals are of that form specifically the weak form of Hilbert's nullstellensatz.

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to show that $\mathfrak{m}=\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\ldots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle$ for some $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{A}_k^n$, where $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ is affine $n$-space.

Now, here is where we use the Nullstellensatz. Note that the Nullstellensatz gives us an order-reversing bijection between algebraic subsets of $\mathbb{A}_k^n$ and the radical ideals of $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$. Therefore, since any maximal ideal is prime and therefore radical, $\emptyset=Z(1)\subsetneq Z(\mathfrak{m})$ implies that $Z(\mathfrak{m})$ is nonempty, so if $\alpha\in Z(\mathfrak{m})$, then it is easy to check that $$Z(\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\ldots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle)=\{\alpha\}\subset\mathbb{A}_k^n$$ and so if $Z(\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\ldots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle)\subsetneq Z(\mathfrak{m})$ then we would have that $\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\ldots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle\supsetneq\mathfrak{m}$ contradicting maximality, so that $Z(\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\ldots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle)= Z(\mathfrak{m})$ and therefore $\mathfrak{m}=\langle x_1-\alpha_1,\ldots,x_n-\alpha_n\rangle$, since both ideals are prime and therefore radical.

Answer (score 3):

This answer from a book: Elementary algebtaic geometry, Klaus Hulek, p25:

> **Theorem:** Let $k$ be a field with infinitely many elements, and let $A=k[a_1,...,a_n]$ be a finitely generated $k-$algebra. If $A$ is a field, then $A$ algebraic over $k$.

In proof of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz we have $K$ is a field and finitely generated $k-$ algebra, then by **theorem** implies that $K$ is algebraic over $k$ then we have $k \hookrightarrow k[x_1,...x_n] \to k[x_1,...x_n]/m =K $
then $K$ is an algebraic extension of $k$ so  $K\cong k$ where $k$ is algebraic closed.